# Django with nginx set current city header

Tags: django, nginx, geoip

I know there is an nginx geoip module, but I'm not pretty sure about how to configure my nginx to deal with it.

What I want is to get the user's city and send it to my Django app, and then to capture that header in the back-end to make some conditions based on the city.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with nginx, take a look at [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/)